# How to overlay density ggplots from different datasets in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have three ggplots `(g1, g2, g3)`.

They are all from different datasets, and they each have the same `xlim` and `ylim`.

I would like to plot them all on one page and overlay them.

I have only found resources online explaining how to plot multiple density plots from the same dataset on the same page.

Is there code I can write so that all subsequent plots are plotted on the same page?

Comment: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/

Comment: This only plots them next to each other, it does not overlay

Comment: You can't overlay plots. You'll need to merge their respective datasets and then create one plot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Phil pointed out you can't overlay different plots. However, you can make **one** plot containing all three density plots. (; Using `mtcars` and `mpg` as example datasets try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(mpg, fill = "data1"), alpha = .2, data = mtcars) +
  geom_density(aes(hwy, fill = "data2"), alpha = .2, data = mpg) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "dataset", values = c(data1 = "red", data2 = "green"))
```

[image]

Comment: My pleasure. If you want do me a favor: Mark the question as answered. Besides giving me or one of the other guys some credit it shows others with a similar problem that the solution worked and removes the question from the queue of questions still waiting for an answer.

Comment: Will do. Another question-- how can I add a legend to the plot? + theme(legend.position = ...) is not working.

Comment: Thanks. Just edited my code to include a legend. Instead of setting the fill color as argument we use the fill aestehtic. Gives us a legend automatically which we can adjust using scale_fill_manual. BTW: theme(legend.position = ... ) only specifies the position of the legend.

Comment: There seems to be a misplaced extra comma in the second line, just before alpha... code still works with (and without!). perhaps best to remove it for clarity (suggest edit queue is full).
geom_density(aes(hwy, fill = "data2"), , alpha = .2, data = mpg)