# Two density plots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

This is really basic. Still hope I can get your help.  I need to superimpose two density plots. The first is a generated normal density plot given mean and sd of AAPL. >

```
x <- seq(-20, 20, length.out = 5113)
normAAPL<-data.frame(x,  f = dnorm(x,mean = meanAAPL, sd = sdAAPL)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, f)) +
  geom_line() + 
  stat_function(fun=dnorm, geom="line", col=2, lty=2)+
  ylim(0,0.2)

> meanAAPL
[1] 0.101133
> sdAAPL
[1] 2.461525
```

The next is the actual distribution

```
dAAPL <-density(oldandnew$AAPL)
```

Where the 20 first AAPL data is

```
c(-8.810021, 1.45281, -9.051401, 4.628075, -1.774445, -5.25055, 
-6.181806, 10.40407, 3.74302, 3.425328, 2.48944, 6.309463, -1.948374, 
-4.652429, 5.493372, -1.852238, -0.1725783, -7.924, 2.074379, 
-3.431709)
```

Do I need to combine the data in one data frame to plot them in the same ggplot?

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overlay density ggplots from different datasets in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918558/how-to-overlay-density-ggplots-from-different-datasets-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(-20, 20, length.out = 5113),
                 f = dnorm(x))

df2 <- data.frame(x = c(-8.810021, 1.45281, -9.051401, 4.628075, -1.774445, -5.25055, 
                        -6.181806, 10.40407, 3.74302, 3.425328, 2.48944, 6.309463, -1.948374, 
                        -4.652429, 5.493372, -1.852238, -0.1725783, -7.924, 2.074379, 
                        -3.431709))


ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x, f, colour = "Normal")) + 
  geom_density(data = df2, aes(x, colour = "Actual")) +
  ylim(0,0.2) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Distribution", values = c("Normal" = "Blue", "Actual" = "Red")) +
  theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position = "top", aspect.ratio = 1)
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jack. Yes that did the job! Thank you.